# Excluding a specific image from some CSS formatting

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, image, sass

I have a bunch of images loaded up on my home page in a grid. Two of these images are loaded directly from the assets folder, whereas the other four are loaded based on whether or not they are selected to be main page items.

Here is the code for the way they are loaded in:

```
    <div class="three_column_grid">
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
            <%= image_tag("1stassetsimage.png") %>
            <%= image_tag("2ndassetsimage.jpg") %>
            <% @product = Product.all %>
            <% @product.each do |product| %>
                <% if product.display_on_home_page and !product.is_highlight_product and !(product == '..') %>
                    <%= link_to image_tag(product.product_image), products_content_url(product.id), :controller=>'products' %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
            <% @subcategory = Subcategory.all %>
            <% @subcategory.each do |subcategory| %>
                <% if subcategory.display_on_home_page and !subcategory.is_highlight_product and !(subcategory == '..') %>
                    <%= link_to image_tag(subcategory.image_attachment), subcategories_content_url(subcategory.id), :controller=>'subcategories' %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As for the CSS itself, this is the way I'm controlling the styling of the various items that come in:

```
           .three_column_grid{
                margin-top: 2%;
                width: 60%;
                position: relative;
                float: right;

                img {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 200px;
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                    margin-left: 2%;
                    margin-right: 2%;
                    margin-bottom: 4%;

                    &:hover{
                        display: inline-block;
                        border: none !important;
                        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have tried a few things; adding an extra div tag that formats just the assets images throws off the whole thing, and using the `:not` selector I get the same result. I want the shadow to be removed around the `1stassetsimage.png` but I want the other formatting to stay the same, so it will fit into the grid correctly.

Comment: Unless the problem is related to the template code itself, only provide the generated HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a class to the excluded tag:

```
<%= image_tag("1stassetsimage.png", class: "plain" ) %>
```

And then "undo" the box shadow for that element:

```
.three_column_grid {
  img.plain, img.plain:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```